# Rendering issue in NextJS

Tags: next.js, tags, rendering

I am using old version of nextjs ^9.2.2 and I have written productName inside

```
<h1>{productName}</h1>
```

Still sometimes on production my page is rendering {productName inside div tag} and that's causing issue to my SEO.
How could I solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide more information? It would be the best if you can create the StackBlitz example. With the limited information provided, I am unable to help you.

Comment: why don't you just update your version? maybe that will help